# PHP regexp replace all matches except the first one

Tags: php, regex

I am using preg_replace to replace **#** with **\n#** from the following string:

```
#0 F:\dev\htdocs\cms\lib\Cms.php(76): 
ReflectionClass->__construct('Mod_Simple_Top_...') 
#1 F:\dev\htdocs\cms\cms.php(45): Cms::renderModules(Array, 
#2 F:\dev\htdocs\cms\bootstrap.php(63): require_once('F:\dev\htdocs\c...')
#3 {main}
```

> preg_replace('/#/' , '\n', $error_message);

The problem is that it also replaces the first match i.e; #0 Is there any syntax in regexp so that it should not consider the first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Find all hash symbols which are *not* followed by a '0'".

```
echo preg_replace('/(#)(?!0)/' , '\n', $str);
```

[→ live example](https://eval.in/74708)

In particular, the group `(?!0)` is called a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: It also replaces the numbers when used in preg_replace. Is there any to just replace the # and not the number

Answer (score 1):

After replace just remove first \n. Use `substr($string, 1)` or `trim($string)`

Comment: Or `ltrim` to avoid losing stuff at the end.